# ImportError: cannot import name '_ColumnEntity' from 'sqlalchemy.orm.query'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pip, apache-superset

After installing apache-superset using pip in virtual environment, I run:

```
superset upgrade db
```

I run into the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_ColumnEntity' from 'sqlalchemy.orm.query' (/Users/ahmedawny/supersetenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: im on the same boat, for some reason theres not a single question like this, or google cant identify characters ldk

Comment: https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/474

Comment: @phd what file do I change that sqlalchemy import?

Comment: How do I know? You haven't shown the full traceback.

Comment: I filed a bug report https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6226

Comment: see also https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/issues/505

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The core reason for this is that sqlalchemy 1.4 shipped, so it is now the default that pip installs. There were many interface changes and a new query interface added.

So upgrading to 1.4 breaks stuff that depends on the sqlalchemy 1.3 API internals. In your requirements.txt file-- pin the project version to the 1.3.x series until the rest of your stuff catches up. For example, as of this date sqlalchemy-utils is still dependent on sqlalchemy 1.3x.

***requirements.txt:***

```
sqlalchemy < 1.4.0
```

Then use:

```
pip -r requirements.txt
```

to "downgrade" to the pinned version.

Comment: Who does breaking changes from 1.3.x to 1.4.0? (sigh)

Comment: latest Flask-Migrate requires sqlalchemy 1.4.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to modify the requirements file, as recommended in [@InsertSpywareTrackingHere's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66648061/3216427), you can manually pip install an older version instead:

```
pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24
```

Comment: Isn't this just a less flexible version of the top-voted answer? Please read [answer].

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30474688)

Comment: While this is equivalent to the top-voted answer, once you know what you're doing, I think this answer has value for the beginner, and I would encourage reviewers not to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to sqlalchemy_utils.functions file and change :

- from sqlalchemy.orm.query import _ColumnEntity (comment this one, or delete it)
- from sqlalchemy.orm.context import _ColumnEntity (include)

in consequence of this, i belive it should change some stuff along the code...

Answer (score 2):

you can temporarily fix this by changing the imports in sqlalchemy_utils\functions\orm.py:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import _ColumnEntity
```

to

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.context import _ColumnEntity
```

Comment: how can i go to sqlalchemy_utils\functions\orm.py
it is installed on online server, pythonanywhere.com

Answer (score 1):

@InsertSpywareTrackingHere answer is correct, Just want to add that a new release for Flask-AppBuilder was made that pins SQLAlchemy bellow 1.4.0. So installing `apache-superset` using `pip install apache-superset` should work now.

Comment: I just pip installed apache-superset fresh.  it complained with  "flask-appbuilder 3.2.2 requires SQLAlchemy<1.4.0, but you'll have sqlalchemy 1.4.7 which is incompatible." but finished.  I still needed to manually pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.24 after.  perhaps the dependency ordering in the setup.py is not right?  I am not an expert.